# how to combine queries from one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with dates and some data. How can I display data for each month (January, February, March), and also display the amount for three months, the average for three months and the maximum payment in one request?

the result should be like this

| users | date | pay | balance | avg(balance) | avg(pay) | sum(pay) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2016-01-30 | 25 | 32 | 37.6 | 21.3 | 64 |
| user_1 | 2016-02-28 | 22 | 39 | 37.6 | 21.3 | 64 |
| user_1 | 2016-03-30 | 17 | 42 | 37.6 | 21.3 | 64 |
| user_2 | 2016-01-30 | 33 | 35 | 31.6 | 21.3 | 95 |
| user_2 | 2016-02-28 | 42 | 29 | 31.6 | 21.3 | 95 |
| user_2 | 2016-03-30 | 19 | 31 | 31.6 | 31.3 | 95 |

I can do this with only two requests

1. `select users, date, pay from table`
   I received data for each month
2. `select users avg(balance), avg(pay), sum(pay), max(pay) from table group by users`

how can I combine these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select t1.users,
       `date`,
         pay ,
         avg_balance,
         avg_pay,
         sum_pay,
         max_pay
 from table_tbl t1 
 inner join 
 ( select users, 
          avg(balance) as avg_balance, 
           avg(pay) as avg_pay, 
            sum(pay) as sum_pay, 
            max(pay) as max_pay 
    from table_tbl 
    group by users ) as t2
    on t1.users=t2.users;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/9

Answer (score 0):

you can use join:

```
select t1.users, date, pay, avgBalance, avgPay, sumPay, maxPay
from (select users, date, pay from table) t1 join 
(select users avg(balance) avgBalance, avg(pay) avgPay, sum(pay) sumPay, max(pay) maxPay from table group by users) t2 on t1.users = t2.users
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a left join to link two query can help you :

```sql
SELECT * FROM table a
LEFT JOIN
    (select users avg(balance), avg(pay), sum(pay), max(pay) FROM table GROUP BY users)
b ON a.users = b.users
```